# How to exclude symlink files from find command?

Tags: sed, find, xargs

I use the following command to do some processing on text files,however it changes the symlink files aswell,is there a way to exclude symlink files from the `find` command and include only the actual files?

```
find . \( -name "*.txt" ! -name "release.txt" \) | xargs -t -n1 sed -i '' -e '/^#/d;/^nocrc=/d;/acaddr=/d;/^$/d;s/[ \t]*$//'
```

Comment: Add `-type f` in your find command

Comment: Or add ```-H```